# Cytoscape GUI is very tiny, Windows 10

Tags: user-interface, display, scaling, cytoscape

my cytoscape GUI is scaled very tiny. I found a solution for MAC in the FAQs, however, I have Windows 10. The display settings of the monitor are 3840 x 2160. Is there a solution for Windows as well?

I have searched the FAQs on Cytoscape website and used google. I am not allowed to change the display settings of my laptop, because this is one that belongs to the lab and many people are using it. If the solution is to change something in the display settings, I will discuss it with the IT. However, for this I need a well justified reason.

Best,
Nina

Comment: Hi Nina.  I know this works now on Windows 11, but don't know about Windows 10.  Typically, changing display settings (adding a scale factor) should be something you can set and then unset, so if you are the only one using Cytoscape, just change the scale factor in display settings to 200% and change it back when you're done...